# animator.SetTrigger not triggering animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

I am currently working on a Beat 'em Up style game, and wanted to set a trigger on mouse1 down to perform a punch using SetTrigger, see code snippet bellow:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        isAttacking = true;
        if (vertical != 0 || horizontal != 0)
        {
            vertical = 0;
            horizontal = 0;
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", 0.0f);
        }

        animator.SetTrigger("Punch");
    }
```

Problem is that the animator.SetTrigger does not recognize the animation name i have given it, and states it is missing that component.

Thank you all.

Comment: note that `SetTrigger` expects the name of a trigger .. not of a state or animation clip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the above issue is to name the trigger parameter in the Animator the same thing I named it in the c